# Do we need Axiom of Choice to prove $|\prod_{i\in J}A_i| \le |\prod_{i\in I}A_i|$ for all $J \subseteq I$ where $I \setminus J$ is infinite?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

To prove the theorem, I try to define a injection $G:\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i \to \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$. I'm able to define $G(\phi)$ for all $i \in J$ by $G(\phi)(i) = \phi(i)$. I feel that to define $G(\phi)$ for $i \in I \setminus J$ is impossible without AC in case $I \setminus J$ is infinite.

---

The **Cartesian product** of a family $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ is defined as $$\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i=\{f:I\to\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\mid f(i)\in A_i \text{ for all } i \in I\}$$

> **Theorem :** Let $J \subseteq I$, then $|\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i| \le |\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i|$.

---

Consider

$$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
G : & \prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i
 & \longrightarrow & \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \\
    & \phi & \longmapsto & G(\phi) \end{array}$$

where $\phi:J \to \bigcup_{i\in J}A_i$ such that $\phi(i) \in A_i$ for all $i \in J$.

$G(\phi)$ is defined by $G(\phi)(i) = \phi(i)$ for all $i \in J$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. It might just be that $\prod_{i\in I\setminus J} A_i$ is empty.

For example, take any $I'$ whose product is empty, and add $J$ as a family with a nonempty product, and $I=I'\cup J$.

If course, once you know that $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ is nonempty, then the statement is true. Simply fix one choice function, and look at the modifications on $J$ given by the choice functions from $\prod_{i\in J} A_i$.

Comment: I would like to understand your ideas correctly, so I paraphrase what you meant in my own words. Please have a check! Thank you so much!

Comment: 1. There are possible cases where  $\prod_{i\in I}A_i = \emptyset$ but $\prod_{i\in J}A_i \neq \emptyset$. Then $|\prod_{i\in J}A_i| > |\prod_{i\in I}A_i|$. For my theorem to be true, $A_i$ must be non-empty for all $i \in I$, or equivalently $\prod_{i\in I}A_i \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: 2. In case $\prod_{i\in I}A_i \neq \emptyset$, by AC, there exists a choice function $f:I \setminus J \to\bigcup_{i \in I \setminus J} A_i$ such that $f(i)\in A_i \text{ for all } i \in I \setminus J$. Then $G(\phi)$ is defined by

$$G(\phi)(i)=\begin{cases}\phi(i) & \text{ for all } i \in J\\
f(i) & \text{ for all } i \in I \setminus J
\end {cases}$$

Comment: @LeAnhDung No, that is not a good paraphrase. The proof is not using the axiom of choice. The description you give does in both cases.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I don't get what you meant by "The proof is not using the axiom of choice. The description you give does in both cases". I intended to write the two above comments and waited for Asaf Karagila to verify them. Then I will edit my post to add an update to reflect those comments. Is anything wrong with my conduct?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo If I added that part before it is verified by Asaf Karagila, it would be an unreliable part and harmful to other readers afterward.

Comment: @LeAnhDung " I don't get what you meant ..." I meant precisely what I wrote. Asaf's proof does not use the axiom of choice. Your paraphrase does.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo But Asaf did mention "Simply fix one choice function..." and "...given by the choice functions..."

Comment: @LeAnhDung More explicitly: Given $J$ and $I$, the inequality you asked about holds if and only if either $\prod_{i\in J}A_i=\emptyset$ or else $\prod_{i\in I\smallsetminus J}A_i\ne\emptyset$. Now, yes, choice is equivalent to the statement that any products of any nonempty family of nonempty sets is nonempty. But the point here is that Asaf is giving you a *local* condition. You seem to be confused by standard terminology: A choice function for the family of sets $\{A_i:i\in I\}$ is, by definition, a member of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo In your first comment *The proof is not using the axiom of choice...*, I initially thought that you referred to my incomplete proof in the post. After your previous comment, I realized that you actually referred to Asaf Karagila's one. That's where my misunderstanding began. On the basis of Asaf Karagila's answer and your comments, I posted a detailed solution in my own words as an below answer so that I can truly understand your ideas. Please have a check on it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @LeAnhDung I took a look and upvoted it.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrésE.Caicedo :) ^^

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of @Asaf Karagila's answer and @Andrés E. Caicedo's comments, I present a solution in my own words here so that I can truly understand their ideas. All credits are given to @Asaf Karagila and @Andrés E. Caicedo.

---

> Suppose $J \subseteq I$. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions that the below inequality holds.  $$|\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i| \le |\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i|$$

There are only two possible cases

1. $\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i = \emptyset$

$I \subseteq J$ and $\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i = \emptyset \implies \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i = \emptyset$. Then $|\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i| = |\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i| = 0$. Hence the inequality holds.

2. $\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i \neq \emptyset$

Then $|\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i| \ge 1$. In order for the inequality to hold, $|\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i| \ge 1$, and consequently $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \neq \emptyset$.

For $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \neq \emptyset$, there exists a mapping $f:I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ such that $f(i)\in A_i \text{ for all } i \in I$. Consider

$$\begin
{array}{l|rcl}
G : & \prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i
 & \longrightarrow & \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \\
    & \phi & \longmapsto & G(\phi) \end{array}$$

where $G(\phi)$ is defined by

$$G(\phi)(i)=\begin{cases}\phi(i) & \text{ for all } i \in J\\
f(i) & \text{ for all } i \in I \setminus J
\end {cases}$$

$G$ **is injective**

For $\phi_1,\phi_2 \in \prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i$ and $G(\phi_1)=G(\phi_2)$. Then $G(\phi_1)(i)=G(\phi_2)(i)$ for all $i \in I$. Then $\phi_1(i)=\phi_2(i)$ for all $i \in J$ and $f(i) = f(i)$ for all $i \in I \setminus J$. Thus $\phi_1 = \phi_2$. Hence $G$ is injective.

Since $G$ is injective, $|\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i| \le |\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i|$, or equivalently the inequality holds.

To sum up the two cases:

The inequality holds $\iff$ $\prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i = \emptyset$ or $\begin{cases} \prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i \neq \emptyset & \\
\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \neq \emptyset & 
\end {cases} \iff \prod\limits_{i\in J}A_i = \emptyset$ or $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \neq \emptyset$